# Mongodb count query to search for strings containing either one string or the other

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I trying to get a count of the documents in a mongodb containing either of the strings(words). I have around 50 words(or strings) . I am aware that i need to use "or" query here.

Here is the query which i tried: But I am not sure if this is correct

```
db.collection.find({"created_at": /^sep 23.*/i, "$and": [{ "text": /.*abc.*/i },{ "text": /.*efg.*/i }]}).count()
```

Comment: Kindly consider accepting the answer that was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) which acts as an OR match against a single field:

```js
db.collection.find({created_at: /^sep 23/i, text: {$in: [/abc/i, /efg/i] }}).count()
```

And you can simplify your regular expressions a bit to remove the `.*` parts because those are already implied.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have not specified that you want to search a specific field in a document, I would suggest the text search option described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

With reference to the doc mentioned above you could use:

`db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "word1 word2 word3" } } )`

space delimited strings are considered as having a logical OR operator between them...

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when I use the query as suggested by you it gives a error message as  "errmsg" : "exception: error processing query: ns=test.tweet4 limit=0 skip=0\nTree: $and\n    created_at regex /^ Tue Dec 16 .*/i\n    TEXT : query=thrown roommates, language=, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query",
 "code" : 2,
 "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/query.js:191
> db.tweet4.find({"created_at": /^ Tue Dec 16 .*/i,  $text: { $search: "thrown roommates"  }})
error: {""

Comment: here is db.tweet4.find({"created_at": /^ Tue Dec 16 06.*/i,  $text: { $search: "thrown roommates"  }}).count()the query i have used :

Comment: Did you create a text index as specified in the doc? refer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/ if you haven't